# Very Basic Numerical Methods Book for Freshman students

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, numerical-methods

To cut a long story short; the nature of this degree (it's not a college degree) is such that numerical methods is treated shortly after Calc I (single-var) and linear algebra, but before multi-var calc or a serious course on probability/statistics (the students got a very basic primer on probability and statistics during a "basic skill-set" subject they took in their first semester, and it's not much).

Do any of you have some suggestions as to what book on numerical methods would suit this target audience? This isn't really the college-level, nor is it the sort of course where you can throw in Fourier-transforms etc.

Affordable texts are preferred, if possible. Digital resources or online notes are strongly discouraged: it should be a physical book. Online notes should only serve to accompany the main text, and are by no means a requirement.

Comment: Applied numerical linear algebra by James Demmel, 1996 could be an option.

Comment: @Svetoslav I was aiming more for a calculus-type numerical analysis kind of book, less for the linear algebra. Think Hildebrand's "Numerical Analysis". However, I'll take a look at your suggestion.

Comment: @Svetoslav I went ahead and took a look at your suggestion. I don't know what made you think this would be the right book for the sort of audience I described. Even the author himself states this book is intended for first-year graduate students. This is **not** a book for freshman undergraduate students, much less for freshman students who aren't even enrolled in a college-level degree to begin with.

Comment: I thought it might help, because a lot of the methods do not require advanced algebra- only linear algebra and normed spaces. But this would mean to follow only some chapters from it.